# Systemd service wanted by multiple targets

Tags: systemd, services

Is there a way to make a service wanted by multiple targets (or to have multiple install directives) so that when installed a symbolic link is created in all places.

My example is the following systemd file

```
[Unit]
Description=Run script to fix-audio mappings

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/usr/local/bin/fix-audio &'
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What this does is run a script to fix the audio mappings for my machine (without it sound only comes from the subwoofer - which is pretty useless). Unfortunately after sleep/suspend/hibernate the mappings seem to reset so I also need this script to be triggered when waking up.

Is there a way to say `WantedBy=multi-user.target,sleep.target` or similar?

I cannot seem to find any documentation about this. Alternatively, is there a better way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes there is, quoting the relevant section of the [man page for system.unit](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html):

> `WantedBy=, RequiredBy=` This option may be used more than once, or a
>   space-separated list of unit names may be given. A symbolic link is
>   created in the .wants/ or .requires/ directory of each of the listed
>   units when this unit is installed by **systemctl enable**. This has the
>   effect that a dependency of type `Wants=` or `Requires=` is added from the
>   listed unit to the current unit. The primary result is that the
>   current unit will be started when the listed unit is started. See the
>   description of `Wants=` and `Requires=` in the [Unit] section for details.
>
> **WantedBy=foo.service** in a service `bar.service` is mostly equivalent to
>   **Alias=foo.service.wants/bar.service** in the same file. In case of
>   template units, **systemctl enable** must be called with an instance name,
>   and this instance will be added to the `.wants/` or `.requires/` list of
>   the listed unit. E.g. **WantedBy=getty.target** in a service
>   `getty@.service` will result in **systemctl enable getty@tty2.service**
>   creating a `getty.target.wants/getty@tty2.service` link to
>   `getty@.service`.

Although if you want to run this for several targets make sure to adjust ordering if necessary (e.g. for shutdown or suspend) via `Before=` or `After=` directives (which are also explained in the man page ;) ).